# My solution is working, I just dont fully understand why: To Do List application MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a To do list application I am developing (Im a complete noob at mvc). I am getting going on the CRUD implementation and I just finished writing the Delete and DeleteConfirmed method. Im not even entirely sure how I figured it out. Something connected and I tried it and it worked but one aspect is boggling my mind.

So I have a list of items with the "edit, details, and delete" actionlinks next to each item (view was generated). So I decided to start with the delete. I made the delete action which is pretty straight forward. Pass in an int id from the form filled out by the user, check if its null, build the table class object, then check if the db table is null at that key then return the view with the tbl object passed in which is the Delete.cshtml view of the object with the "Delete" button below it. 
The next action I wrote is the DeleteConfirmed() which actually handles deleting and saving changes to the database (if im understanding that correctly?). How does this button link to the DeleteConfirm() action? I just cant seeem to connect the dots and I dont want to move on until I understand it.

for reference, controller methods:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            using (MyBasicListAppEntities db = new MyBasicListAppEntities())
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                tblBasicList tbl = new tblBasicList();
                if(tbl == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(tbl);
            }
        }
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            using (MyBasicListAppEntities db = new MyBasicListAppEntities())
            {
                // Find the row based on id from form (primary key)
                tblBasicList tbl = db.tblBasicLists.Find(id);
                // remove the whole row at that id
                db.tblBasicLists.Remove(tbl);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("MyToDoList", "Home");
        }
```

Delete.cshtml:

```
@model MyBasicListApp2.Models.DB.tblBasicList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>tblBasicList</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InputDate)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputItem)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InputItem)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputImportance)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InputImportance)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCompletion)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemCompletion)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

main page with the list: MyToDoList.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBasicListApp2.Models.DB.tblBasicList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyToDoList";
}

<h2>MyToDoList</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputItem)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputImportance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCompletion)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputItem)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputImportance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCompletion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BasicListID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BasicListID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "List", new { id=item.BasicListID }, null)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
</table>

<h4>Would you like to add another item?</h4>
@Html.ActionLink("Add more", "ToDoList", "List")
```

Also the InputItem just shows up as a blank box in the Delete.cshtml view. The other displays show their values but not inputItem (less important to me to figure out right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your ActionLink will generate a hyperlink, which means it's a GET request to the server.

MVC has some smart defaults that send that link click to the Delete action in your controller.

When you submit the form that is created in the `delete.cshtml`, however, that will be a POST request (based on the defaults generated by the `Html.BeginForm()` helper).  If you notice the C# Attribute above your DeleteConfirm action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
```

that's telling the framework that this action should be invoked for POST requests against the Delete route for this controller.

/** Edit for the second part of the question **/

When you call `return View()` in your `Delete` action, you're passing it the `tbl` object, which is just a `new tblBasicList()` based on the code you posted.  If there is no default value for InputItem, then it'll be blank.

If you want the current object, you need to fetch it from the db and then send the fetched item down to the view.

Comment: Man thank you! That was driving me crazy. Any idea on why the inputitem isnt showing in the view? Ive debugged and the value is there, and it gets removed from the table. It just doesnt show in the view

Comment: Well, the code you posted in your Delete action just creates a new object and sends that down to the view.  If your default value for InputItem is blank, then it's not going to have anything there.  If you want the current values for everything associated with that ID, you'll need to fetch it from the DB before rendering the view.

Comment: as an aside, I'm a big fan of the APress MVC books, for getting started: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Experts-Voice-ASP-Net/dp/1430265299/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463099723&sr=8-1&keywords=apress+asp.net+mvc

Comment: Thank you! I will check them out now